# Building dynamic tags in existing Word/PDF templates

Tags: docusignapi

We have hundreds of Word DOCX templates with unique placeholder tags at certain positions within them. Imagine tags such as {FULLNAME} and {JOBTITLE} etc. Our back-end processing performs simple find-replace commands at run-time to build new DOCX documents based upon these templates while replacing these tags with data from our database. For example, find all {FULLNAME} and replace with John Smith. We also have DOCX with bookmarks and even PDF templates with fields, they all basically work the same.

At the end of all this a set of documents are built (and optionally converted to PDF). Now, we wish to begin using DocuSign API to start accepting data from our clients. This is data we don't know from our database. Imagine {SPOUSENAME} or {DATEOFBIRTH} etc. We don't have this information, we want to ask our customers. We also want them to sign the documents at certain positions on the page which already have text tags like {NAME1SIGNHERE} and {NAME2INITIALHERE}.

We don't want our employees to manually build DocuSign templates, having to position fill-in fields and signature fields on our templates. Further, we don't want to have to build hundreds of DocuSign templates which closely match all of our original templates to match them up.

We simply want to use our existing documents and dynamically recognize these unique text tags placed all over them to build an envelope for certain people to complete and sign.

For example, each time we find "Do you want to work overtime? {CHK_OVERTIME}" we would know to place a new DocuSign checkmark tag element at the location where {CHK_OVERTIME} is located.
Another example would be, "Please sign here: {NAME1SIGN}" and now we know to replace {NAME1SIGN} with an actual DocuSign signature tag element to accept John Smith's signature (because we know John is Name1 in this transaction).

Our project is .Net Framework (not MVC or Core)... what is the best approach here?
Thanks!
David

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to build out a robust set of Anchor Tags: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/

So, using your `{SPOUSENAME}` example: If your document processor finds it doesn't have a matching bit of information, instead of replacing that text with the name, it could instead color the text white in the document so it does not appear to be visible. Then, in the API Call to DocuSign, you could add a tab definition like

```
"tabs": {
    "TextTabs": [{
        "anchorString": "{SPOUSENAME}",
        "tabLabel":"Spouse_Name",
        "required":"true",
        "recipientId":"1"
    }]
}
```

so that a text tab is placed over the blanked-out text in the document, and the signer is prompted to fill it in.

Checkboxes, SignHere and InitalHere tabs could all behave the same way. Leave the `{CHK_OVERTIME}` or `{NAME1SIGN}` text in the document (recolored to match the background so it's hidden, and reduced font size as needed) then add the appropriate tags to your envelope definition when you're passing it to DocuSign.

A C# code example is available here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-composite-template-embedded/

Comment: Using this method and reading the documentation I have questions: First, it appears that there needs to be existing composite templates previously defined in DocuSign and referenced by template ID. However, our templates would be dynamically generated so DocuSign would not already have them. Second, it appears that I must submit templates in HTML (sent as Byte) but ours are in DOCX format (which could be converted to PDF if necessary). We would need to build dynamic, custom docs ready to be signed for which DocuSign has never seen.

Comment: That's fine - Composite Templates _can_ reference a server template defined in DocuSign, but there's no requirement that they do. For you, the key objects under a Composite Template will be the `Document` parameter (where you can add your DOCX's base64 and the appropriate `FileExtension`, and the `InlineTemplate` parameter where you will define recipients, tags and other envelope properties.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for pointing me in this direction. I will explore it further.